# How can I get the value of any String variable from one component to another component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

This is My first component

```
posteddata: string;


public Submit() {
var UserResponses = Object.assign({}, ...this.responses);
console.log(UserResponses);
var headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
this.http.post(this.python,UserResponses).subscribe(data => {  
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    this.posteddata = value;
    console.log(this.posteddata);
    this.pred.addprediction(this.posteddata);
    Object.entries(this.recommend.categorys).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(value.type.includes(this.posteddata)) {
        this.router.navigate([`/result`]);
      }else {
        return exit;
      }
      }
   );
 });
})
```

}

I want the Value of "this.posteddata" which I am getting it when I hit submit from the python model directly and I want to use the same value in another component of angular

Comment: You can use a service for that.

Answer (score 0):

If your components are not in a parent/child relation, you can store variables in a shared service to use them in another component

Service:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class SharedService {
       public yourVariable: unknown;
    }
```

Component that gets the data:

```
    [...]
    constructor(private readonly _sharedService: SharedService ){ }
    [...]

public submit(): void {
[...]
this._sharedService.yourVariable = data;
}
```

component that needs the data:

```
 [...]
 constructor(private readonly _sharedService: SharedService ){ }  
 [...]

public get yourVariable(): unknown {
return this._sharedService.yourVariable;
}
```